# tabbaritem image not changed

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am changing the image of a tabBarItem depending on a context

```
    if (user == nil) {
        self.navigationController?.tabBarItem.title = "Login"
        self.navigationController?.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "login")
    } else {
        self.navigationController?.tabBarItem.title = "Home"
        self.navigationController?.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "home")
        self.view = homeView()
    }
```

But when I have my view replaced by homeView the image is not changed, but the title is changed.

[image: Logged screeen]

Once I tab to other item I have it changed:
[image]

How I can make it changed right after redirecting to the HomeView?

Answer (score 1):

I Think I found the problem (not tested yet).
It doesn't work because there's a difference between the tabBar's image and it's **selected** image.
Just add this line:

```
else {
    self.navigationController?.tabBarItem.title = "Home"
    self.navigationController?.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "home")
    self.navigationController?.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "home")
    self.view = homeView()
}
```

Comment: Oww, then I don't know. I am surprised it didn't work, it sounded hopeful